# String is not a function : Error AngularJS(factory) MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I am playing around with the MEAN stack. I have created a rest service to delete from mongo db which works fine but When I try to use angular Factory method and call it I get the above error

```
 myApp.factory('methodFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
         return {
            //id becomes undefined over here
            removeContact:function($http, id){ 
                //TODO add URL
                var url = '/contactlist/'+id;
                return $http({
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    url: url
                });
            }
        };
    }]);


 myApp.controller('AppControl', ['$scope','$http','methodFactory', function($scope,$http,methodFactory) {

    $scope.remove = function(id) {
            console.log(id); //able to print correct id

            methodFactory.removeContact(id).success(function(response){
                console.log("remv"+response);
                refresh();
            });//tthiss throws the error

            //this rest service works properly.
            /*$http.delete('/contactlist/'+id).success(function(response){
                console.log("remv"+response);
                refresh();
            });*/

        };
};
```

This what node server looks like

```
app.delete('/contactlist/:id',function(req,res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.contactlist.remove({_id:mongojs.ObjectId(id)},function(err,doc){
        res.json(doc);
    });
    console.log("exiting delete")
});
```

I am not sure if factory could be one of the way to call a rest service. What could cause the problem ?
Error

```
TypeError: string is not a function
    at Object.removeContact (http://localhost:3000/controllers/controller.js:10:20)
    at l.$scope.remove (http://localhost:3000/controllers/controller.js:85:23)
    at hb.functionCall (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:198:426)
    at Cc.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:215:74)
    at l.$get.l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:126:193)
    at l.$get.l.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:126:419)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:215:126)
    at HTMLButtonElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:32:363)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your removeContact method needs two parameters:

```
removeContact:function($http, id) ...
```

but you call it with only one:

```
methodFactory.removeContact(id) ...
```

Id is a string, I suppose, but it it will be assigned to the first parameter of the function $http, what must be executable according the code you provided.